# A JSF Pages from Entity Classes wizard for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, facelets, crud, wizard

I wonder if there is a JSF Pages from Entity Classes wizard like the one in NetBeans for Eclipse to generate Facelets files for CRUD Capabilities.
thank you